# foreach loop update only last value three times in table

Tags: php, mysql

[image: See this picture of my page]
This is a code to update a table with foreach loop. But it update the last value three times which is POST[s3_name]

```
<?php
$names = [$_POST['s1_name'], $_POST['s2_name'], $_POST['s3_name']];
$query = "update students SET Name=:Name WHERE ProjectID='$id'";


foreach ($names as $name) {
try
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $msg = "Record updated";
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{  
   $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: You need to bind $id like you do with name.. and it's overwriting because you're not changing the ID each loop interation

Comment: First of all, learn about SQL Injection. http://bobby-tables.com - Your code is not safe at all and your whole database could be deleted within a few seconds, without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. Then to solve your problem: Learn how to create an array.

Comment: like how can you tell? @clearshot66

Comment: I suspect that that `$id` is coming from a `POST`, but since that portion of code is not posted, then I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that this is a sql injection risk. You are properly binding `:Name` so it's all good for the code we are seeing. I do 100% agree that you aren't changing your `id` through each iteration and so you are updating the same record over and over again.

Comment: ProjectID is same for three post element. so how can i changed it?

Comment: I'm assuming you have multiple records in `Students` with the same `projectID`. The database will not iterate through each record as part of your for loop, so you may have to rethink your design here. Essentially the database just updates all rows with that `projectID` with the `name` being supplied. Multiple records, each iteration. You have to spell out which individual record you want to update with the specific name you are applying.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that only the last name will prevail since it's, well, the last one.

Comment: Just run, in phpmyadmin or whatever: `UPDATE students SET Name="Hi" Where projectID = <some project id>` You will see ALL rows for that projectID get updated to "Hi" for the name, which is definitely not what you want. You have to get exact with your update statement like `UPDATE students SET Name="Hi" WHERE studentID = <some student id> AND projectID = <some project id>;`.

Comment: I am getting these values from form   $id=$_POST['project_id'];
$ptitle=$_POST['pt'];
$s1_id=$_POST['s1_id'];
$s1_name=$_POST['s1_name'];
$s2_id=$_POST['s2_id'];
$s2_name=$_POST['s2_name'];
$s3_id=$_POST['s3_id'];
$s3_name=$_POST['s3_name'];

Comment: Ultimately though the entire thought of:  "I have a table named `Students` and a `projectID` in this table may be assigned to many `Student` records. I want to update all records for a given `projectID` to the list of names supplied in the POST?" is indicative of bad design. It sounds like perhaps a connector table would be more appropriate. `Students` (with student attributes), `Projects` (with project attributes), and `Student_Projects` (with `StudentID` and `PRojectID`). That connector table you can `INSERT`/`Delete` from, no funky UPDATE necessary.

Comment: i have three separate table. projects, students and progress

Comment: project table includes : (pk)ProjectID and ProjectTitle

Comment: students table :  (pk)RegNo , (fk)ProjectID, Name

Answer (score 0):

You could get the id from somewhere and loop that as well. Something like this

```
$names = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name2'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'name3']
];


foreach ($names as $name) {
    try {
        $query = "update students SET Name=:Name WHERE ProjectID=:Id";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);  
        $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $name['id']);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $msg = "Record updated";
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {  
        $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
    }
}
```